# SVG title tooltip not showing on text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, tooltip

I need to have a tooltip show up on mouseover of an SVG Text element. Everything I find on the net says to add a Title element as the first child of the SVG element. It works in Chrome, but not in Safari which is the primary browser of my user base.

Here is simplified example showing my situation. The

```
&#xf0eb;
```

is a FontAwesome lightbulb icon that is the element I want the user to mouseover and have the tooltip come up on.

```
<svg ...><text><title>some text</title>&#xf0eb;</text></svg>
```

Ideas?

Comment: I ended up resolving this by using jQuery tooltip instead of the the SVG title which I never got working. Leaving the question open as it's unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following snippet in Safari 12.1 and the tooltop "some text" showed up as expected.  Perhaps you are testing with an older version of Safari, or maybe you are using a plugin that is affecting this feature?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <text x="10" y="20" class="fas">
    <title>some text</title>
    &#xf0eb;
  </text>
</svg>
```